# Cannot get Linq syntax to work

Tags: c#, linq

I have, what to everyone else will probably be quite a simple bit of logic, but I've been going round in circles and can't figure it out.

I'm using Entity Framework, however this is not too important as it is the Linq part I need advice on.

I have an named Category and another named Offer. The relationship is that an offer can have 1 category, and of course a category can have many offers.

Each offer has 2 bool columns: **IsActive** and **IsExpired**.

I'm trying to select only categories that have at least 1 valid offer (that is **IsActive** and **!IsExpired** )

Although I'm using a repository, it's essentially the same, where r is the Categories table.

```
        return r.Find()
            .Any(x =>  x.Offers.Where(y => y.IsActive == true));
```

This is one big syntax error. Help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you have mixed up the `where` and the `any`. Try:

```
return r.Find().Where(x => x.Offers.Any(y => y.IsActive));
```

Answer (score 1):

try nesting any  inside of where.

```
return r.Find()
       .Where(x => x.Offers.Any(y => y.IsActive));
```